# Flutter Navigator “tipo de argumento 'Context' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo de parâmetro 'BuildContext'”

Tags: android, flutter

Estou tentando navegar para uma outra pagina no flutter, sendo assim eu inseir a linha:

Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));

porem o context da esse erro:

The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.

alguém ai poderia ter uma solução?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled/src/componentes/cardCarrinho.dart';
import 'package:untitled/src/pages/loginPage.dart';

class carrinhoPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _carrinhoPageState createState() => _carrinhoPageState();

}

class _carrinhoPageState extends State<carrinhoPage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            CardCarrinho(),
            CardCarrinho(),
            CardCarrinho(),
          ]

      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: _TotalContainer(),
    );
  }
}
    Widget _TotalContainer(){
      return Container(
        height: 185.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 10.0,
          right: 10.0,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 30.0,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget> [
                   Text(
                      "Subtotal",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                    Text(
                        "23,0",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                 SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
               Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Taxa de Entrega",
                          style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                 Text(
                 "3,00",
                   style: TextStyle(
                       color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                       fontSize: 16.0,
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                 ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Total",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                "26,00",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)  => LoginPage()));
          },
            child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
             child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Finalizar Pagamento",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF9BA7C6),
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código? Veja se [este](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66800) ajuda

Comment: Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)  => LoginPage()));
          },

Comment: Essa linha de codigo serve pra navegar entres janelas...mas por alguma razao que nao sei qual o context da erro.

Comment: Como a mensagem de erro contém `'JsObject' ` então nesse código postado não é possível identificar a causa. Localize no seu código. É possível que seja um `loginPage.dart` espere algum parâmetro.

Comment: Na pergunta vc diz que esta fazendo um Navigator.push(); Mas no código vc esta usando um Navigator.pop(context).push(... Esta certo isto?

Answer (score -1):

Talvez o erro esteja na forma como está passando a navegação do context entre páginas. Tente usar dessa forma:

`Navigator.of(context1).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context2) => Container()));`

**Navigator** : Encontre a instancia de Navegador mais próxima dentro da árvore de widget

**of(context1)**: Começando por esse contexto(context1)

**.push(… (context2)…)**: Então a partir do contexto onde foi encontrado o Navegador, insira a nova página na pilha de páginas dentro de seu próprio contexto(context2).

Créditos: https://blog.flutterando.com.br/entenda-o-buildcontext-do-flutter-895e4d01054e